# Can I have separate color for some Photoshop guides

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, page-layout

While designing a web site layout in Photoshop, on a 960 grid, sometimes we want to put some extra guides to use along with our main guides.

**Is there a way to give a separate color to some individual Guides?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately, no.**

All guides in Photoshop are controlled by the single color set in the **Preferences**. There is no way to have guides of varying color. And, in fact, this is true of all Adobe software.

That being posted, there's nothing stopping you from creating a layer with vector paths drawn on it to use as guides.